# Check androidx support for Xamarin Form

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

How can we check if application supports only AndroidX and and not Android for Xamarin Forms application?

I have few applications developed with Xamarin Forms and I want to check if I have to upgrade them to AndroidX or not as Android support is going to stop.

Thanks

Comment: Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to know the `Android Support Library` was created to provide newer features on older versions of Android. It is a compatibility layer that allows developers to use functionality that may not exist on all versions of the Android operating system and have graceful fallbacks for older versions. The Support Library also includes convenience and helper classes, debugging and utility tools, and sophisticated classes that depend on other Support Library classes to function.It has had a long history of over the last 7 years providing backwards compatibility to Android framework APIs. Over the years, this library has grown in adoption as the majority of Android apps in the Google Play Store use the Support Library in some fashion today.

`AndroidX` is a replacement for the Support Library, which is no longer maintained - all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library. AndroidX is a redesigned library that uses semantic versioning, clearer package names, and better support for common application architecture patterns. AndroidX version `1.0.0` is the binary equivalent to Support Library version `28.0.0`.

Xamarin.Forms added support for automatic `AndroidX` migration in version `4.5`.

So it doesn't force you to use AndroidX or Android Support,however as the Support Library grew in complexity,it becomes more and more chaotic.AndroidX is recommended for future projects.

Even if you're using `Support library` now, you could migrate it to `AndroidX`,you could refer to [AndroidX migration in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration) and [Androidx for Xamarin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-for-xamarin/)